# Laptop fan not turning on for graphics

Tags: drivers, debian, graphics-card

About two years ago, I purchased a samsung series 5 (**not** the ultra book, the [NP510r5e](http://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer/office/mobile-computing/notebook/NP510R5E-S01CA)). Every now and then, when there I run something graphically demanding, the laptop just shuts down.

I first noticed the problem when using google maps with satellite view, and recently again when playing a game. It starts, and some five seconds later everything is off. I am not quite sure, but I think the laptop has *Hybrid Graphics*, i.e. one low consumption graphics card (Intel, embedded in the CPU) and one that's more powerful (ATI Radeon). However, `lspci` only lists the Intel one:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

I think there are two different problem. First, the ATI card is not recognized. Second, the fans are not going on for the CPU embedded graphics card (I don't hear anything) which overheats and has everything shut down. I run lots of simulations keeping my cores quite busy, and cooling has never been a problem. Only with graphics.

I have been running Debian wheezy and jessie and had the problem with both. I only realized recently that I had those second graphics (the ATI) so it is not my priority making them work; rather I'd like my computer to regulate its temperature first. Any suggestion?

Here's some output:

```
$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +53.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)
temp2:        +53.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +53.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +53.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +51.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

and I'll gladly submit a `lshw` as well.

Comment: Driver information for the Intel and AMD GPU would be nice.  "Second, the fans are not going on for the CPU embedded graphics card" - So you mean the CPU's fan does not turn on ever?  You have a hardware problem replace the fan.

Comment: @Ramhound : What kind of information are you interested in? I can't find the AMD GPU info on my computer, I am just relying on the info from Samsung's website for thinking that there is one. The fans will start working if the CPU is computing something, or running a program. Just not for graphics.

Comment: That does not make sense.  The GPU is contained within the CPU die itself.  This still points to a CPU fan problem which I would replace.  Yes I realize its a laptop, and it will be tough to find the part, but the CPU fan not turning on indicates that its broken and the fan you do hear isn't that fan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem (or at least a solution). It seems my computer is not able to deliver as much power to my GPU as its supposed to; I rewrote `/sys/class/drm/card0/gt_max_freq_mhz`, which is the file that sets the max frequency for my Intel GPU. It was 1300Mhz, and now with 1000Mhz everything seems stable.

Answer (score 0):

You should run a cpu stress tester such as Prime95 to rule out an issue with the cpu fan. This would generate a lot of heat without stressing the graphics card and if your laptop survives a few minutes it is safe to say the CPU fan is working properly. Depending on how the secondary graphics card is implemented it is possible it might not show up as a device unless it is activated.

I recommend after ruling out a CPU fan issue you test with windows and the most up to date drivers from your manufacturer website to determine whether it is a Linux driver issue or a hardware issue. If the same behavior is observed in windows you should look into replacing the gpu fan.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I ran some stress tests, and monitored the temperature, and it seems it is not a fan problem after all. It did not crash at all during the stress test, and when it crashes doing other things, temperature is not even eighty celsius. I assume it is the power supply that is failing. Also, I read that Linux doesn't crash from overheating, it just shuts down (nicely). I can't seem to find any way to monitor the voltage/current/consumption, though.

Comment: Linux will crash from overheating, if it can detect it early and shut down before the cpu or other components reach the critical threshold it might, but if the cpu hits its critical threshold it will power off the system regardless of what software is running. Running prime95 only rules out a cpu issue, you may want to try a gpu stress test now. I doubt it is a power issue because if the laptop has a working battery and is attached to the power adapter, both would have to be broken in order for the laptop not to get enough power.

Comment: I stressed the GPU as much as I could, along with the CPU. The whole thing (gpu is embedded) heat to tops 85 celsius, but no crash. I think it is definitely not a fan issue (the temperature is not that high when the crashes happen). Could it be of the same kind as overclocked CPU crashing?